# Magento2 is stable or not?

Tags: magento2

I have new product of eCommerce,
I just want to know should I use Magento 2 or not for this project?
As I seen in many posts people are saying that you can go through magento 1.9 only for now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Magento 2 is not stable yet.
The release is planned by the end of 2015 (but there are so many bugs yet...).
A Magento 2 team member had answered the question [2 days ago](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/1771#issuecomment-136768809).

Answer (score 2):

Magento 2 is currently in Merchant Beta Release.

The Magento 2 general availability (GA) is planned in Q4, 2015.

Link:

http://magento.com/blog/technical/magento-2-merchant-beta-release

Comment: What would be the release date for Magento2 EE?

Comment: and again, as we all know it will be "production ready" by version 2.7 - 2.9 LOL :)

Answer (score 2):

**Magento 2 is stable from 17 november 2015.**

magento team have launched Magento 2.0.0 General Availabilty.

**Magento 2 is Stable Now.**

Comment: It's 2018, and its far from stable.